# What is the best practice ti make a horizontal table? iOS

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, tableview

With only tableView or with Collections?
Now I read tutorial:

[how to make an interface with horizontal tables like the pulse news app part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)

but it about tableView, is it necessary to use Collections and what it gives to me?

UPDATE If I want only one table cell in the bottom with images(with touchable actions), what should I do?

Comment: You can create horizontal scroll easily with UICollectionView but if you want to use UITableView then [horizontal-scrolling-in-Table-in-IOS](https://github.com/govindaraokondala/horizontal-scrolling-in-Table-in-IOS) can help you.

Comment: If I want only one table cell in the bottom with images(with touchable actions), what should I do?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting. Means one Cell containing horizontal scroll only? and rest of cell should not contain horizontal scroll?